# Charts in ExtJS3

Tags: charts, extjs3

I'm using ExtJS3 and i want to put this chart into a panel with a dynamic store
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/chart/pie-chart.html

I tried to include this chart into my panel code but it didn't work.
Does anybody has a solution or an example for a chart included into a panel in ExtJS3

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I used your example to generate the chart using a dynamic store:

```
Ext.chart.Chart.CHART_URL = 'http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/resources/charts.swf';

Ext.onReady(function(){
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: "sample_data.php",
    root: 'results',
    fields: [
         {name: 'season'},
         {name: 'total'}
    ]
});

    new Ext.Panel({
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        title: 'Pie Chart with Legend - Favorite Season',
        renderTo: 'container',
        items: {
            store: store,
            xtype: 'piechart',
            dataField: 'total',
            categoryField: 'season',
            //extra styles get applied to the chart defaults
            extraStyle:
            {
                legend:
                {
                    display: 'bottom',
                    padding: 5,
                    font:
                    {
                        family: 'Tahoma',
                        size: 13
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

where `http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/resources/charts.swf` is the target where you can find the chart and sample_data.php returns the following json:

```
{"results":[
    {"total":"150","season":"Summer"},
    {"total":"245","season":"Fall"},
    {"total":"117","season":"Winter"},
    {"total":"184","season":"spring"}
]}
```

**Note**: This should normally be set to a local resource.

Hope this helps.